# Find all unique values from array of strings across mongo documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a mongo collection, I want to collect all unqiue values from an array of strings. The documentation tells me the $reduce function is the way to go, but I don't see my mistake.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  values: ['1','2','4']
},
{
  _id: 2,
  values: ['1','3','5']
}
```

The desired output is a simple array of `['1','2','3','4','5']` where all strings are unique.

My attempt (I am trying to do this in nodeJS):

```
db.collection
      .aggregate([
        {
          $project: {
            'values': {
              $reduce: {
                input: '$values',
                initialValue: [],
                in: { $concatArrays: ['$$value', '$$this'] }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ])
```

Error:

```
$concatArrays only supports arrays, not string
```

For details see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/d4efHev2fUm)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/7XLsj36-4HQ

Comment: @cmgchess's playground should work well for most of the scenarios. If you are facing an extreme case of a lot of documents with many repeated values within the `values` array, you may breach the 16MB single document size during the `$group` stage when `$push`. You can first `$unwind` and `$addToSet` in the `$group` stage like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4QFNJ0ao7xB). However, `$unwind` could be expensive. If you don't foresee the extreme case mentioned, you should just stick with @cmgchess's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `$unwind` and `$group` something like below

`db.getCollection("test").aggregate([{$unwind: "$values"}, {$group: {_id: null, uniqueArray: {$addToSet: "$values"}}}, {$project: {"uniqueArray":1, _id: 0}}])`